# Python combining two text files with dictionaries - with column number inconsistancies

Tags: python, file, text

I have two text files I need to combine using a common key that both have.  I can read them both into python dictionaries but am still having a significant problem.  For example:

**File-1:**

```
Sample Criteria1 Criteria2 Criteria3 Criteria4 Criteria5 Criteria6
A      1         5                   98        3
B      2         4         56        12                  34
C      3                   99        45        33
```

**File-2:**

```
Date   Sample Metric2 Metric3 Metric4 Metric5
9      A      5               98      3
8      B      4       56      12
2      C              99      45
```

I want following:

```
Sample Criteria1 Criteria2 Criteria3 Criteria4 Criteria5 Criteria6 Date   Sample Metric2 Metric3 Metric4 Metric5
    A      1         5                   98        3               9      A      5               98      3
    B      2         4         56        12                  34    8      B      4       56      12
    C      3                   99        45        33              2      C              99      45
```

This is my code:

```
project = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")
table = open(sys.argv[2], "rb")
outfile = open(sys.argv[3], "w")

projectdict = {}

for line in project:
    parts = line.strip().split("\t")
    projectdict[str(parts[1])] = line.strip().split("\t")

tabledict = {}

for line in table:
    parts = line.strip().split("\t")
    tabledict[str(parts[0])] = line.strip().split("\t")

for key in tabledict:
    outfile.write(key + "\t" + str(tabledict[key]) + "\t" + str(projectdict[key]) + "\n")

project.close()
table.close()
outfile.close()
```

What I'm getting is this:

```
    9      A      5               98      3    9         A         5      98     3
    8      B      4       56      12      8    B         4         56     12
    2      C              99      45      2    C         99        45
```

The word "Sample" is also causing a `KeyError` message and as a result I'm not getting my column headers in the output either.

I had hoped using dictionaries would prevent this problem.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Actually, the output is a little different than posted as the contents of file one are first and then the contents of file two but the general idea is that the empty field are not being retained.

Comment: Probably don't need all the `str` functions if this is a text file, nor the `'rb'` just `r` or `rU`. You are loading the whole line as an entry with the key of the second element in the line? For testing, just `print` your output instead of writing to the file. The last call to the dictionary just uses the last value of tabledict's keys?  That doesnt exist in projectdict because you used field 1 instead of 0... Problems in the logic here!